# Server change request documentation

Tags: untagged

Is there anywhere that can provide a template for a server change request document?

Comment: what kind of changes? What industr[y|ies]? The requirements for a small business will be vastly different than those surrounding a financial services company.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these that I've run into have depended a lot on the change-control process of the company in question. Approvals needed, details required, and suchlike all change from company to company. However, a good change-request form should have:

- A description of what will be changed
- A description of how this will affect functionality
- Details about what testing has been done to verify this change is safe
- Details about how to back out the change once it's in place (if possible)
- Whatever documentation your approvals process requires

Somewhat more optional details:

- Description of what conditions will trigger a backout
- Details about why this change is needed
- A risk-assessment surrounding doing this change versus not doing this change